# Assigning tasks to persons, use drag and drop with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Please look at this photo:

[image]

There are 2 tables (or just 2 columns of one table) called Tasks and Persons, the number at the right of each row in Persons table shows max number of tasks that the person can take over.

I want to do:
**Once I drag a task to a person, it becomes like that photo.**

Does anybody give me some suggestions to do that by javascript, jquery or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear Mark Hall, thanks so much for adding that image to my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it already, this is what I need http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart

jquery ui provided a very similar example thing.

Answer (score 0):

For Visualizing it, you could use http://raphaeljs.com/ together with jQuery UI's Drag And Drop Functions. Demos are below, just scroll down

E.g: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Comment: Your link is great but it's just for "Visualizing", it's not exact what I need. Anyway, thanks so much.